# Why does this code print the ASCII value instead of the character

Tags: java

I thought typecasting to char we do the trick but it just prints ascii values

```
   String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");

   str = str.toUpperCase();
   String temp = "";

   for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++)
   {
       temp += (char)str.charAt(i) + 1;
   }

   System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: `str.charAt(i) + 1` is the likely culprit

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's implicit conversion from `char` to `int`. You're casting it to a `char` then adding 1 onto it. Put some brackets in.

Comment: Assuming you're trying shift to the next character, trying using `temp += (char) (str.charAt(i) + 1);`, which takes the `char` adds `1` to it (resulting in an `int`) and then casts the result back to `char`

Comment: Just to demonstrate the point , essentially u are doing something like `temp += (int)str.charAt(i) + 1;`

Comment: @sean what do you think the temp contains if `str.charAt(i) is 'a'`. Although OP wants the next alphabetic character not some `int` value.

Comment: Alright thanks everyone! adding the brackets sorted it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is you are adding integer 1 to char . 
This will return the ASCII code of the next char.

Change to

`temp +=  (char)(str.charAt(i) +1)`

Comment: Correct, but why, I'd be nice to provide some background information to the OP so they understand better their mistake and not fall into the same trap again

Comment: these "change to" kind of things should be comment if they are short enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding + 1 and that is causing it to be converted to integer I am not sure if explained properly just remove it

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention in my question that i was trying to print the next char, but thanks for your answer